# How to detect bottom to top touch in horizontal RecyclerView item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, touch

How to detect bottom to top touch in horizontal Recyclerview item?
I want to display a toast when the user pulls the finger vertically onto the item.

Answer (score 0):

may it will help you

```
recylerView.smoothScrollToPosition(0);
```